# fastapi, html and forms. How to no load new page?

Tags: python, html, browser, fastapi

I have made a little demo to show the problem I am trying to fix.

app.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Form
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from pathlib import Path

app = FastAPI()
BASE_PATH = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory=str(BASE_PATH / "templates"))
g_word = ''

@app.get('/word', response_class=HTMLResponse)
def word(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse('word.html', {'request': request, 'word': g_word})

@app.post("/submit")
def submit(request: Request, word: str = Form(...)):
    global g_word
    g_word = word
    print (g_word)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8001, log_level="debug")
```

word.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Word page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/submit" method="post">
  <label for="word">Word:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="word" name="word" value={{ word }}><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

structure

```
app/
├─ app.py
├─ templates/
│  ├─ word.html
```

When I click on the submit button the browser actually loads the submit url and displays "null". Is there any way to make it so the browser doesn't load the submit page. Is this even the correct way of doing this?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to keep the original page loaded by using a hidden iframe...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Word page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/submit" method="post" target="frame>
  <label for="word">Word:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="word" name="word" value={{ word }}><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<iframe name="frame" style="display:none;"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```